# Javascript Reflection: Determine if Single or Double Quoted String used to create object

Tags: javascript, reflection

I come from c# world, and there you can determine almost anything about any piece of code.

Because javascript has 2 syntaxes for defining strings 'single' and "double", i was curious if it is possible to determine which was used to create a particular string in an object. Anyone know how/if this can be done?

I'm just messing around, trying to "rebuild" a src file from an object, and got stuck on this particular point.

I've tried JSON.stringify(object) but that seems to give inconsistent results..

Comment: In C#, are you able to determine if a string was created by `string s = "foo"` or `string s = string.Format( "{0}", "foo" )` using reflection? Same here.

Comment: yeah that would be rather difficult..